# Gin / Gwt / Eclipse: com.google.gwt.inject.Inject cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: eclipse, gwt, dependency-injection, guice, gwt-gin

I'm trying to use GIN (Guice for GWT) within eclipse. The tutorial says to add a line to my module xml file:

```
   <inherits name="com.google.gwt.inject.Inject"/>
```

However, when I do this Eclipse reports an error "com.google.gwt.inject.Inject cannot be resolved to a type"

I've added gin.jar, aopalliance.jar and guice.jar as referenced libraries. What else do I need to do?

Comment: What are your GWT and Gin versions?

Comment: Gin version is 1.0, from the download page on the gin site.

GWT version is 2.0.3.

Eclipse version is 3.5.1.

Comment: Do you get that error only by including the jars to the project and the inherit declaration or are you adding some Gin code too? (Damn, I remember having the same issue long time ago, I can't remember how I fixed it then >_<) Hmm, as a last resort - have you tried checking out the source from svn and building the gin.jar yourself?

Comment: I get the error when I add the inherits clause to the module xml file. I haven't tried building the gin source, but I will do so.

Comment: Could you also check if you can compile (to js) the project? Sorry for such baseless suggestions - I'm just trying to recreate whatever I did back when I had the same issue :)

Answer (score 1):

Did you import the guice-assistedinject jar, i think you need that jar as well

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, I deleted gwt-UnitCache and it worked...

Answer (score 0):

What operating system do you use? I've heard that some releases of Gin have problems with chmod privilages on unix a like systems.